# Images in data-src div not showing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Using a Twitter Bootstrap theme, deploying to Heroku, images inside the slider won't display.

I have some images inside a data-src div attribute, when I deploy to Heroku the images do not display. They are inside a slider.

If used this code then image (slide1.jpg) don't show locally OR on Heroku:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="camera_wrap pattern_4 camera_emboss" id="camera_wrap_4">
                <div data-src="<%= image_tag("slide1.jpg")%>">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromTop">
                    <h1>Template</h1>
                    <span>Some text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

If used this code then image (slide1.jpg) shows up locally but NOT on Heroku:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="camera_wrap pattern_4 camera_emboss" id="camera_wrap_4">
                <div data-src="/assets/slide1.jpg">
                <div class="camera_caption fadeFromTop">
                    <h1>Template</h1>
                    <span>Some text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Could it have something to do with the Javascript of the slider? Thoughts on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer:  I remebr having problems with images not loading in Heroku.  I can't remeber excatly how I fixed it - but from memory
1- rake assets:clean
2- RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
Hope this helps
Pierre

Comment: Tried this, no luck. Thanks.